# Annoying Recruiters

Tags: recruitment, australia

I am looking for a job, so I apply for jobs in one jobs websites in Australia.

What I have realized is that I get many calls from recruiting agents, asking me many questions (it takes around 15 min conversation) and at the end there is no job opportunity.

The conversation goes mainly about my existing work, number of employees, my manager title, etc. and at the end, they tell me about a role that is totally not suitable for me at all; and they know that from the beginning.

After having many of these conversation, I found out that they just collect information in order to chase my existing company with offers to help them recruit people.

I am worried that they might approach my manager and the manager sense I am applying for jobs.

Beside that, I hate wasting time on someone who uses me and my need to find another job as a bait.

How can I stop these? I don't want to be rude, especially that I am afraid one day the agent is really having a job for me?

Comment: How are they getting your number? Is it published on the job site? Are you responding to advertisements?

Comment: _"I don't want to be rude.."_ you simply can't be ruder than any recruiter - they own that game, so don't worry ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found recruiters in Australia especially annoying for this, and it's even more annoying when you're actually looking for a job. When you're not looking then you can just screen your calls, but not if you're actually going to be interested in some of them.

One technique is instead of just passively answering their questions, take some early control of the conversation. For example:

> Recruiter: *Hi, this is John Smith from Cold Call Recruitment, do you have five minutes to talk?*
>
> You: **Hi John, sure, what position are you calling about?**

Then it could go one of two ways:

- The recruiter has an actual position to discuss, and you can have a real conversation with them about it.
- The recruiter just wants another CV in their database, and you can end the call when they don't have any specific position to talk about.

Answer (score 6):

You ask them questions as soon as they ask a question such as :

> Recruiter : what is your job title?
>
> Your reply : it is X, what are the job title and responsibilities? What is the salary? What is the benefits package?

As soon as they brush off your questions you know they are fishing and you can close the call.

Comment: I'm a contractor, so slightly different situation. I can lead with salary/rate question without coming across as overly money driven. Asking for an outrageously large amount will result in the recruiter closing the call very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Your post comes across as a bit of a rant (which I agree with all of them, I'm also in Australia and am not a fan of recruiters).

There's too many "wolf of wall street" type recruitment companies competing with each other, which may or may not be a bad thing in general. But I agree with the other poster, you need to take control quickly or you'll find yourself in an impromptu phone interview you never wanted trying to sell yourself for a job that doesn't exist.

The only question I could see you asked is:

> How can I stop these?

You can change your number or find out where it is published and unpublish it.

Is it on your resume? on Linkedin?

I have my Linkedin set to "not currently open to opportunities" - it has slowed the calls/mails down but not completely stopped them.

Obviously not much you can do for those who already have your number.